# Android Loop Faster After KeyBoard Slides Out / Configs Changed

Tags: java, android

I have a basic game loop shown below. But when I slide the keyboard out, the loop runs way faster. I don't understand this because my delay time does not change. Before - After is constantly 1 or 2 milliseconds. Can anyone explain why this is happening. -Thanks

```
public abstract class GameLayout extends LinearLayout {
// App context
private Context context;
// Timer period
private long mPeriod =75;
// ---------[ GAME LOOP ]-----------------
protected Handler gameHandler;// = new Handler();
private Runnable gameRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        long before = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        gameLoop();
        postInvalidate(); // causes UI to be redrawn
        long after = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        long delay = mPeriod-(after-before);
        if (gameHandler != null) {
            if(delay >0)
                gameHandler.postDelayed(this, delay);
            else gameHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }
    }
};

protected void startUpdateTimer() {
    // System.out.println("start timer");
    gameHandler = new Handler();
    gameHandler.post(gameRunnable);
}
enter code here
protected void stopUpdateTimer() {
    // System.out.println("stop timer");
    gameHandler.removeCallbacks(gameRunnable);
    gameHandler = null;
}

public void setUpdatePeriod(long updateDelay) {
    mPeriod = updateDelay;
}

// -----------------------------------------------------
public GameLayout(Context c) {
    super(c);
    context = c;
}

public GameLayout(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(c, attrs);
    context = c;
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    try {
        // Init game
        initialize();
        /**
         * start update task. Which will fire onDraw in the future
         */
        startUpdateTimer();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // bug
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`onLayout` happens pretty frequently, and certainly would be kicked off once or twice by a rotation. You're not stopping the old instance of the `gameHandler`/`gameRunnable`, leading to the `gameRunnable` being kicked off once on each layout. Without actually seeing your `gameLoop` source it's impossible to know, but there's probably shared state causing multiple instances of the `gameLoop` you have running at once to cause problems - make sure you only are running one one `gameHandler` at a time (try logging some unique information about the Handler before executing the gameLoop to see if that's the case).